# An equation to prove with terms of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

I would like to prove an equation but I have stuck. The equation that is to prove is the below:

$f(n)^2 + (-1)^{n+1} = f(n+1)f(n-1) , n \ge 2$.

I'm trying to do an inductive proof of this equation. I have stuck at this line of the proof: $f(n)*f(n-1) - f(n+1)f(n-2) = (-1)^{n+1}$.

I do not know whether this method is right or not, and if I have to do another kind of proof instead of induction. I just want to prove it.

I ask for your help!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This comes from a [determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form). The matrix formulation for the Fibonacci sequence is well worth knowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's odd; you shouldn't need that.  One can proceed as follows: Assuming that we know

$$
F^2_n-(-1)^n = F_{n+1}F_{n-1}
$$

we can write

$$
\begin{align}
    F^2_{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1}
        & = F_{n+1} (F_n+F_{n-1}) + (-1)^n \\
        & = F_{n+1}F_n + F_{n+1}F_{n-1} + (-1)^n \\
        & = F_{n+1}F_n + F^2_n \\
        & = (F_{n+1}+F_n)F_n \\
        & = F_{n+2}F_n
\end{align}
$$

which was the desired equality.  (Along with, of course, the basis case $1^2 = 1 \cdot 0 - (-1)^1$.)